# How can I change the favicon in Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

I have been trying to change the favicon in my Laravel project, but still couldn't. This is information on how I am trying to do it.

[image: Documents]
[image]

And the code I'm using inside the Head is this:

```
  <link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.ico') }}">
```

Comment: When you view the site with the developer's tools open to the network tab what do you see? Is it different when you force it to ignore cache? What is the html that the page renders for that link? Can you access the favicon directly? Is the server software set up with the right MIME type for .ico files?

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear cache in the browser

```
 1. Clear browser data in Microsoft  :
 2. Press the keys [Ctrl], [Shift] and [Del].
 3. A new window opens. Select an option like clear images and files on the cache.
 4. Confirm your selection by clicking on the "delete" button
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="114x114" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.ico') }}">
```

Comment: It still don't work. Maybe is because i'm doing it in the Blade's layout? I have tried in a web host too, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please try <link rel="icon" href="{!! asset('images/favicon.ico') !!}"/>  or < link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.ico') }}" >

Comment: No, it don't work either. I really don't know what is happening.

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" 
 href="/assets/images/favicon.ico"/> please try this static path reference from https://www.creative-tim.com/live/material-dashboard-laravel

Comment: I have already solve it. I had to put the link in every page, not only in the layout. Thakns anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That is already correct. Try forcing the browser to refresh the favicon by hashing the link with a random string, e.g:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.ico') }}?v={{ date('YmdHis') }}">
```

The url param "**v**" with the timestamp value will force the browser to fetch the favicon.ico again if it is already cached on the browser.

Comment: It still don't work. Maybe is because i'm doing it in the Blade's layout? I have tried in a web host too, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these two things:

1. Since your code is correct, you just need to refresh your page many times to force your browser fetch new information from your application.
2. Clear browse cache if the above(1) doen's resolve the issue.